# C++ Error 1 error C2664 passing array pointers

Tags: c++

I don't understand how fix this problem, tried many things but no solution. Help on it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

> Error 1 error C2664: `'void showAllBuses(const Bus *[],int)'` : cannot convert argument 1 from `'Bus **'` to `'const Bus *[]'`

```
void showAllBuses(const Bus* pBuses[], int numBus) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numBus; i++) {
        cout << "Bus no ." << numBus << " details: " << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << pBuses[i]->getNumber() << endl;
        cout << "Driver name: " << pBuses[i]->getDriver().getName() << endl;
        cout << "Driver experience(years): " << pBuses[i]->getDriver().getYearsDriving() << endl;
    }
}

void listBusesWithYearsDriving(const Bus* pBuses[], int numBus, int drivingYears) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numBus; i++) {
        if (pBuses[i]->getDriver().getYearsDriving() >= drivingYears) {
            cout << "Bus number: " << pBuses[i]->getNumber() << endl;
            cout << "Driver name: " << pBuses[i]->getDriver().getName() << endl;
            cout << "Driver experience: " << pBuses[i]->getDriver().getYearsDriving() << endl;
        }
    }
}

void removeDriver(Bus* pBuses[], int busPos) {
    pBuses[busPos]->removeDriver();
}

void main() {
    const int ASIZE = 4;
    int drivingYears = 0;
    Bus* buses = new Bus[ASIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < ASIZE; i++) {
        addNewBus(&buses[i]);
        cout << "Bus " << i << ": " << &buses[i] << endl;
    }
    showAllBuses(&buses, ASIZE);
    cout << "Please enter a minimum years of experience to look for: " << endl;
    cin >> drivingYears;
    listBusesWithYearsDriving(&buses, ASIZE, drivingYears);
    removeDriver(&buses, 0);
    showAllBuses(&buses, ASIZE);
    delete[] buses;
    buses = nullptr;
    cout << "\n\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any type `T`, `T*` can be implicitly converted to `const T*`, but `T**` **cannot** be implicitly converted to `const T**`. Allowing this would make it possible to violate constness<sup>(1)</sup>.

A `T **` *can* be converted to `const T* const *`, though. Since your function does not modify the array in any way, you can simply change its parameter like that:

```
void showAllBuses(const Bus* const * pBuses, int numBus) {
```

Bear in mind that in a function parameter declaration, `*` and the outermost `[]` are synonyms.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Here's the code:

```
const int C = 42;
int I = -42;
int *p = &I;
int *pp = &p;
const int **cp = pp;  // error here, but if it was allowed:
*cp = &C;  // no problem, *cp is `const int *`, but it's also `p`!
*p = 0;  // p is &C!
```